# Accessing the original object inside each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check or uncheck all the checkboxs the following code works for me

```
 $( '#chkboxall' ).live( 'change', function() {

                                objs=$(document).find('#chkbox');
                objs.each(function(){
                                $(this).attr( 'checked', $(this).is( ':checked' ) ? '' : 'checked' );
            });
                 });
```

But instead of using  `$(this).is( ':checked' ) ? '' : 'checked'`  i want to get the status of original checkbox that i have checked ie status of $('#chkboxall' ). How can i do that inside each?

Krishnik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten it without the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) here (since [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) can run on every element in the set already):

```
$('#chkboxall').live('change', function() {
  $(document).find('#chkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

*However* this isn't valid, you have a repeated `chkbox` `id` attribute which is invalid.  Give those elements a class instead, like this:

```
<input name="blah" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Then use a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) in your code:

```
$('#chkboxall').live('change', function() {
  $('.chkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

---

For others finding this in a different situation, to get a reference to the "outer `this`" inside a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), just set a variable, like this:

```
$('#chkboxall').live('change', function() {
  var thing = this;
  $('.chkbox').each(function(){
    //thing = the outer this, the #chkboxall element
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nick its working and i have updated the html markup and now i'm using class instead of id. Thanks again.